# Coroutines not running in parallel

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a few suspend functions that make a network call in my `WorkManager` that I am trying to get to run in parallel using Coroutines so I was trying to use `async` in them but they seem to still be executed sequentially.

Example:

```
suspend fun call1() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    async{
        Log.d(TAG,"Call 1 started")
        delay(2000)
        Log.d(TAG,"Call 1 fiished")
    }
}

suspend fun call2() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    async{
        Log.d(TAG,"Call 2 started")
        delay(5000)
        Log.d(TAG,"Call 2 finished")
    }
}

suspend fun call3() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    async{
        Log.d(TAG,"Call 3 started")
        delay(1000)
        Log.d(TAG,"Call 3 finished")
    }
}
```

I call them like this

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result{
    setForeground(createForegroundInfo())
    call1()
    call2()
    call3()
    return Result.success()
}
```

When I run this I see the log messages show up as in order just as they are called and the next call does not start until the previous one finishes. What I was expecting is `call3` to finish first then `call1` and finally `call2` but it just gets call1, call2, call3.

What am I missing to get these to execute in parallel?

Comment: Where do you call `.await()` on the deferred objects?

Comment: @aminography Why do you need to call await? it was my understanding that you only need to call await if you want the result? In this case I dont need any result

Comment: AFAIK it should not start a coroutine until the `await()` gets called. In your case, it's better to use fire-and-forget coroutine builder which is `launch` instead of `async`.

Comment: @aminography the coroutine executes and does the work regardless of await or not.

Comment: Changing from `async` to `launch` didn't make a difference either it still takes the same amount of time to execute them (8 seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a new scope for each one, they would be launched in parallel:

```
suspend fun call1() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    Log.d(TAG, "Call 1 started")
    delay(2000)
    Log.d(TAG, "Call 1 fiished")
}
```

#### Update:

Although the above solution works in parallel, but you can not keep track of the coroutines which causes a possible execution leak. To preserve structural concurrency it's better to do it like the following:

```
suspend fun call1() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Call 1 started")
    delay(2000)
    Log.d(TAG, "Call 1 fiished")
}

suspend fun call2() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Call 2 started")
    delay(5000)
    Log.d(TAG, "Call 2 finished")
}

suspend fun call3() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Call 3 started")
    delay(1000)
    Log.d(TAG, "Call 3 finished")
}
```

And then:

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result{
    setForeground(createForegroundInfo())

    coroutineScope {
        launch { call1() }
        launch { call2() }
        launch { call3() }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "After all finishings")

    return Result.success()
}
```

Comment: Just want to point out, they aren't run sequentially merely because they are launched in the same scope. (Indeed the solution above calls them sequentially in the same scope.) They were each launched inside `withContext` blocks, making each `async` Job a child of the respective `withContext` calls, which were called sequentially. You could have called them all on the same scope but without the `withContext` wrapper, and they would have run in parallel: `fun CoroutineScope.call1() = async(Dispatchers.IO){//...`. But of course, the code in the UPDATE is the better way to do it.

Comment: @Tenfour04: You are right. Thank you for your supplementary note.